# How to have separators between cells using balham theme?

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I love [AgGrid's Balham theme](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-themes/balham-theme.php) but I'd like to have separators between the cells. Just like the separators between the column's headers.

I am using AgGrid Enterprise 19.1.4 with Angular 7.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to put in some CSS to the ag-cell. Here is an example:
https://plnkr.co/edit/EyJEtF7wzWsdpzCJFzGm?p=preview

```
.ag-theme-balham .ag-ltr .ag-cell {
  border-right: 1px solid #aaa;
}
```

The example uses CSS class selector `.ag-theme-balham .ag-ltr .ag-cell` as that is the CSS selector ag-Grid uses for border-right, so it overrides what the grid puts. If you want a simpler selector, just put !important to make sure the new CSS get's used and not the grids.

You could also look at generating our own theme, explained here:
https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-styling/

However creating your own theme would be overkill just for adding a border.

Comment: Hi Niall, I know this is an off-topic comment, but I see you have another [SO profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4638931/niall-crosby), you should try merging them. Go through this link: https://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts.